# sql insert into statement that excludes no existent data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that is inserting data into a table for 12 months. It is for an automated report. Everything works except that the report is for a full year. My data thus shows a lot of zeros for all the future months and the report is aesthetically pleasing. How do I change my script so that it only populates the months where data exists.

```
declare @sql1 varchar(max),@sql2 varchar(max),@sql3 varchar(max),@sql4 varchar(max),@sql5 varchar(max),
        @sql6 varchar(max),@sql7 varchar(max),@sql8 varchar(max)
        
declare @month1 varchar(10),@month2 varchar(10),@month3 varchar(10),@month4 varchar(10),
        @month5 varchar(10),@month6 varchar(10),@month7 varchar(10),@month8 varchar(10),
        @month9 varchar(10),@month10 varchar(10),@month11 varchar(10),@month12 varchar(10),
        @month13 varchar(10),@month14 varchar(10)   

IF OBJECT_ID('TransferDutyReport01.dbo.tmpTDReportTable1', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE TransferDutyReport01.dbo.tmpTDReportTable1; 


        
set @month1 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(mm,0,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month2 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,1,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month3 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,2,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month4 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,3,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month5 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,4,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month6 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,5,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month7 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,6,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month8 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,7,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month9 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,8,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month10 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,9,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month11 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,10,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month12 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,11,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month13 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,12,GetDate()),112),6)
set @month14 = LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(mm,1,GetDate()),112),6)




-- ===================
-- ==== ALL CASES ====
-- ===================

set @sql1 = 
'
    




create table TransferDutyReport01.dbo.tmpTDReportTable1
(
    INDVOL varchar(50) ,
    INDVAL varchar(50) ,
    [Month1] dec(17,2),
    [Month2] dec(17,2),
    [Month3] dec(17,2),
    [Month4] dec(17,2),
    [Month5] dec(17,2),
    [Month6] dec(17,2),
    [Month7] dec(17,2),
    [Month8] dec(17,2),
    [Month9] dec(17,2),
    [Month10] dec(17,2),
    [Month11] dec(17,2),
    [Month12] dec(17,2),
    [Month13] dec(17,2)
)      
'

set @sql2 = 
'
insert into TransferDutyReport01.dbo.tmpTDReportTable1
(INDVOL,Month1,Month2,Month3,Month4,Month5,Month6,Month7,Month8,Month9,Month10,Month11,Month12,Month13)
select ''1 Distinct cases'' as INDVOL,
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month1+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month2+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month1 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month2+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month3+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month2 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month3+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month4+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month3 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month4+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month5+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month4 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month5+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month6+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month5 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month6+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month7+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month6 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month7+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month8+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month7 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month8+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month9+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month8 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month9+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month10+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month9 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month10+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month11+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month10 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month11+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month12+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month11 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month12+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month13+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month12 + '],
count(distinct case datecreated >= '''+@month13+'01' +''' and datecreated < '''+@month14+'01' +''' then ccasenum end) [' + @month13 + ']
from
(
 select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by ccasenum order by datecreated asc)rown from TransferDutyReport01.dbo.tmpTDCasesAlerts2
)qq where rown = 1
'



exec(@sql1)
exec(@sql2)
```

Note:
I am only showing a portion of the script. There are in fact 8 variables being declared. I have tried declaring a date so that it only looks at records up until today, this didn't work. I also messed around with if exists, where exists, etc. Everything I do kicks out an error. I also tried countif, this also gave me an error. For clarity purposes, this is not my script, it is inherited, I just need to make it work. Original developer has left the company.

Comment: Syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);` cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection; which is what you are doing. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement, which you should be doing here.

Comment: If truth, whether to *display* the column or not sounds like a task for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: So instead of exec @sql2 I say sys.sp.executesql? and this will allow solve my problem?

Comment: Also, syntax like `'[' + @ColumnName + ']'` isn't injection safe; you should be usinh `QUOTENAME` to *safely* escape the values.

Comment: *"and this will allow solve my problem?"* No, it'll enable you to parametrise your query; just switching to `sys.sp_executesql` won't do that alone though, you'll need to correct your dynamic statement and pass the parameters to the procedure.

Comment: I am using a matrix in SSRS in Visual Studio. This was my starting point but it's my first time using this software so I haven't been successful. I will post a different question asking for help here instead. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: *"I am using a matrix in SSRS in Visual Studio."* then using dynamic column names makes little sense. YOu should be using the matrix to completely pivot your data.